# How can I append a react JSX component to html via Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I created a custom toast component as seen below:

```
<Snackbar
    open={open}
    autoHideDuration={6000}
    onClose={handleClose}
    message="Note archived"
    action={action}
  />
```

I don't want to attach it to every page I create in my react app. Instead, I want to create a static function that I can use to call it. Something like this:

```
Swal.fire(
  'Good job!',
  'You clicked the button!',
  'success'
)
```

But for this to work, I have to append a component to the HTML. Please how can I achieve this. I tried doing this:

```
    ReactDOM.render(<OvToast
    content="hello"
    handleClose={() => console.log('this is it')}
    open
    title="success"
    type="success"
  />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

but it removes all the content of the page except the toast.
Please how do I append Jsx to a HTML? I want to achieve a toast message.

Comment: You can create another element in your HTML and add the toast to that instead of adding it to the `#root` element. A better solution will be to add the toast as a child of an already rendered component.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `render()` function all the contents of the target element is removed and the new content is loaded. If you want to append the content to existing HTML you can create a new `<div>` (or any other element) and append the element. Then render the contents in the newly created element.

```js
function App() {
  return <React.Fragment>hello friend</React.Fragment>;
}

const div = document.createElement("div");
document.querySelector("#root").append(div);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(div);
root.render(<App />);

// Or if you are using React 17 or lower:
//
//     ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
//
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root">
  <p>existing content</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to append a JSX element, like the one I showed above

Comment: @Thanoss This example should give you the the understanding to do so. You can replace `<App />` with your `<OvToast content="hello" ... />` component.

Answer (score 0):

change your mind The correct way is to add that component to app.js.

Then, using redux, set the value of message and boolean etc... to show or hide the component .

Now you can change the value of message and isShow on any page you want using redux.